# Join 3 tables with 2 where clauses

Tags: sql, join, where-clause, multiple-tables

I have problem with sql query. I need to join 3 tables with 2 where clauses.

First table is:

**new_product_to_category**

```
product_id|category_id
3|1507
3|1507
4|1507
```

Second is:

**new_product_to_store**

```
product_id|store_id
3|2
3|3
4|2
```

The Last one:

**new_product_description**

```
product_id|name
3|something
4|something2
```

And the query looks like

```
SELECT pts.product_id, pd.name FROM new_product_to_category ptc 
                LEFT JOIN new_product_to_store pts ON pts.product_id = ptc.product_id AND pts.store_id = 3 
                LEFT JOIN new_product_description pd ON pts.product_id = pd.product_id 
                WHERE ptc.category_id = 1507
```

I need to get result only with products which are in CATEGORY 1507 AND ARE FROM STORE 3... is that possible? Thanks for replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT pts.product_id, pd.NAME
FROM new_product_to_category ptc
LEFT JOIN new_product_to_store pts ON pts.product_id = ptc.product_id
LEFT JOIN new_product_description pd ON pts.product_id = pd.product_id
WHERE ptc.category_id = 1507
   AND pts.store_id = 3
```

Having the validation in the WHERE clause will make it so that you get all the records from new_product_to_category, with all the information from new_product_to_store and new_product_description that it can find (LEFT JOIN) and at the end you limit to the ones that match the WHERE clause.

By having the validation in the ON clause, you will make it so that you get all the values from table products, but only have content from new_product_to_store for the ones that have store_id = 3.

Trying both the queries in sqlfiddle, you can see the difference when doing SELECT *, and you can see why you would have more results for your query.

EDIT:
Having store_id also in new_product_to_category you should also add that validation to the ON clause (ptc.store_id = pts.store_id):

```
SELECT *
FROM new_product_to_category ptc
LEFT JOIN new_product_to_store pts ON pts.product_id = ptc.product_id 
     AND ptc.store_id = pts.store_id
LEFT JOIN new_product_description pd ON pts.product_id = pd.product_id
WHERE ptc.category_id = 1507
  AND pts.store_id = 3;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/356846/4)</kbd>

Comment: I made mistake. The new_product_to_category table has another column with store_id, so it looks like this [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/356846/1
And it returns 2 same products. Second is right, but first one with id 3 from category 1507 but from store with id 2 is wron

Comment: And what do you want it to do?

Comment: @JonášASabína. I added a query to my answer that will fix that. Can you undestand why it works?

Comment: I have another question. What if I have some other products in new_product_description but they are not categorized and are not in store (the other two tables are the same). Is here way how to fetch only them?

Comment: You can do that with: SELECT * from new_product_description WHERE product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id from new_product_to_category ) AND product id NOT IN (SELECT product_id from new_product_to_category ).

Comment: Will this work even if i have ONE PRODUCT in MANY CATEGORIES in one shop? Is there need to use DISTINC? Thanks

Comment: nope. if you want to find what are the ones that don't belong to the other tables, you will end up with that.